# Trouble changing background color of TextField in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I just started building my first App with Codename One and I'm having quite some trouble. :-)

I cant change the background color of a TextField, I changed everything in the Theme and named it "TextField". At the Color tab I changed the background color and set Transparency to 255. Since the Component is named TextField, shouldnt the style be applied automatically when I make a new TextField?

I also tried to set the UIID manually to "TextField", which didn't help either.

Am I missing something?

Kind regards,

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way backgrounds work in Codename One is this:

- Border is applied first
- Then image
- Then gradient
- Then color

`TextField` and other components such as `Button` etc. often have a default border derived from the theme.

Switch to the `Border` tab, click `derive` then click the `...` button and select `empty`.